# Execute the query in SSMS without highlighting, while the query separator semi-colon is placed at the end?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Has anyone found a solution to execute the query in SSMS like Oracle style ctrl+enter? I hate scrolling and highlighting the query. I'm using SSMS 19.3

Comment: I collapse the query so that I only have one line to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle like ctrl+enter shortcut isn't provided (as at time of this comment). The method in SSMS is to highlight the query or portion of it that you want to execute and then press F5 or use the "Execute" button.

You could try making your own shortcut by using the "Tools" menu and selecting "Options," then "Environment" and "Keyboard".  Assign your shortcut to the "Query.Execute" command from the list. However I'm not sure if this will remove the need to highlight (and so it may not suit your purpose).